# Sharepoint List Calculated Column isn't displaying correctly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

My SharePoint List has a calculated column based on the item ID which is auto generated.

It's a simple text function `="SR-"&TEXT(ID,"0000")`, which works fine, but the last few items added are all showing the value SR-0000, despite ID being 457 and 458.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot of list showing issue]

Answer (score 0):

It works well in my environment.

[image]

Try to use rest to get the current item, and check what is the value saves in the column.
[image]
The displayed data may be changed by other logic, such as JSON formatting.